# What movie features a boy in a wheelchair who eventually becomes a cyborg?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I want to remember one movie, it’s from the 80's or early 90's (or maybe even 70's), about a boy in wheelchair who eventually becomes cyborg.

There are also this guy's friends, one girl and one other guy who at the end of the movie shoots this cyborg with a crossbow, but cyborg catches the arrow and removes his mask to show who he is.

I'm sorry. I only remember this mess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The TV show *M.A.N.T.I.S.* featured a hero who normally is in a wheelchair, but when he puts on his hero suit he has full use of his limbs.  He's sort of a part-time cyborg.  At the time I thought that was a new plot idea, but looks like *Exo-man* did it decades earlier.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.A.N.T.I.S.

Comment: Proposed duplicate target is newer but has a clearer answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They only thing that comes to mind is ***Exo-man*** (1977).
This show was the pilot for a series that never materialized.
It's about a genius who survives a mob hit but is paralyzed and he builds himself a suit of armor that not only enables him to walk but also to fight crime too.

Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGb0y7pm52g) and here's the [imdb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076008/).

**UPDATE:**
Okay, how about [Prototype X29A](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105183/) (1992)? It has a silvery cyborg who originally can't walk.  And there's a friend with a bow and arrow.
Here's a [long synopsis](http://www.dollartheatermassacre.com/2013/05/prototype-x29a-is-not-your-typical.html) of the movie

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not it. Cyborg has silver glossy costume. And its more modern that Exo-man.

Comment: That's it! :)) Thanks alot :))